# SwiftUI: Cannot Delete List Item If Just Viewed

Tags: ios, list, image, swiftui

I have a very odd issue.  I have a list app that crashes when I delete a list item that I just viewed.  I can delete an item that is different than the one I just viewed without the crash.  The crash error is:

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/XXX/Documents/Xcode Projects Playground/Test-Camera-CloudKit/Test-Camera-CloudKit/DetailView.swift, line 20

Line 20 of the DetailView.swift file is the line that displays the image/photo [Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: myItem.photo!) ?? UIImage(named: "gray_icon")!)].  Below are the files from my stripped down app to try to run this issue to ground.  I am using CoreData and CloudKit.

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State private var showingAddScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(myItem: item)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.name ?? "Unknown name")
                        }
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Items")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAddScreen.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            )
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
                AddItemView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let item = items[index]
            moc.delete(item)
        }
        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting objects")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

AddItemView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @State private var image : Data = .init(count: 0)
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name of item", text: $name)
                }
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {self.show = true}) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                            }
                        }
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "gray_icon")!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 300, alignment: Alignment.center)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$show, content: {
                        ImagePicker(show: self.$show, image: self.$image)
                    })
                }
                Section {
                    Button("Save") {
                        let newItem = Item(context: self.moc)
                        newItem.name = self.name
                        newItem.photo = self.image
                        try? self.moc.save()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Item")
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddItemView()
    }
}
```

DetailView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @ObservedObject var myItem: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myItem.name ?? "Unknown")
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: myItem.photo!) ?? UIImage(named: "gray_icon")!)
                     .resizable()
                     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                     .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 300, alignment: Alignment.center)
                     .clipped()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(myItem.name ?? "Unknown"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    static var previews: some View {
        let item = Item(context: moc)
        item.name = "Test"
        return NavigationView {
            DetailView(myItem: item)
        }
    }
}
```

ImagePicker.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ImagePicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var show : Bool
    @Binding var image : Data
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        
        return ImagePicker.Coordinator(child1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator
            return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var child : ImagePicker
        
        init(child1: ImagePicker) {
            
            child = child1
        }
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.child.show.toggle()
            
        }
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            let image = info[.originalImage]as! UIImage
            
            let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.45)
            
            self.child.image = data!
            self.child.show.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I am really struggling with how does the app have an error in a view that is not being shown when an item is deleted.  The list items does get deleted and removed from CloudKit.  The delete operation works.  The crash and error happens whether the coredata attribute for the photo has a photo or not.  In other words, it has the error even when the item does have a photo and is not nil.  Where am I going wrong?  How do I get it to allow me to delete an item that I just viewed in the DetailView without a nil error?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive. You are force-unwrapping a nil value.

Comment: I understand the message, but how is it nil.  I can show the data in both variables (name and photo) in the DetailView.  They are not nil.  Then delete the item in the ContentView and it says the photo is nil.  How is that. That is what I don't understand.  Any idea?

Comment: It's not possible for us to know how it's nil since you didn't share the code for `Item` and how it's populated. In general, it's not a good practice to use `!`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that piece.  Item is a CoreData entity with attributes id (UUID), name (String), and photo (Binary Data).  All are three are set to Optional.  photo is set to Allows external Storage.  Used with CloudKit is checked for the Default Configuration.  Codegen is set to Class Definition.  The only other think I changed in the code is I added the to lines to the AppDelegate.swift for CLoudKit.  container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy